# Help in deciding setting

Tags: fantasy, world-building, setting

I'm writing a fantasy story, I'm still planning the plot and characters, I have an idea about the setting, but I'm divided about the technological level of the setting. It is more of an adventure story, that's inspired by manga such as Fullmetal Alchemist, One Piece, and games like Final Fantasy VII.

I'm confused what should I do with the setting, whether there should be electricity, and cars etc. Any advises?

Thanks

Comment: This is very broad. You will have to develop more of your plot, your characters, and your theme to determine the setting. Some plots are not dependent on setting or can be adapted to different times (c.f. Sherlock Holmes), and some only work in a particular time period (WWII stories). Until you figure out more of the story you want to tell, we can't help you to figure out when and where it should be told.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll work on it a lot and then get back to you folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best things about those stories, especially the Final Fantasy series, is that the technology changes drastically from continent to continent and village to village. In most cases there is the evil empire or corporation that is technologically superior, but only because they cull it from everything and everyone around them.

The poverty stricken could be simple farmers or hunter/gatherer types who fear the technology that has oppressed them.

Another great thing is that magic can play a factor. Maybe the magic in your book is your electricity, or maybe it is a forgotten power which the hero holds the key to and the villain is seeking at all costs. Maybe the magic is far more powerful than any tech in the known world.

Books like that are popular right now because they identify with the struggle of modern life and the knowledge that there is a select 1% of humanity that is so rich and powerful that we may just be kept in the dark and controlled so that they can stay powerful.

Even still, your question is very broad and I'm not sure that any of this is applicable to your ideas and concept. Hopefully this helps with the technology question. Ultimately, I think a wide range of technology is best, it opens your book up to have more locations and differing landscapes in terms of a Manga or FF style storytelling.

Comment: I've divided the world in four zones, so ranging technological levels sounds about right. Thank you.